# Can you skip the bootloader with GCC/Cortex-M0+?

Tags: gcc, arm, bootloader, cortex-m

I'm writing fairly simple production test application for a small ARM Cortex-M0+ controller ATSAMD20J16. I'm using Microchip (Atmel) Studio 7 for this purpose. This will have a bootloader in production, which is a black box from my point of view. It'll jump to address 0x0800 when done, which is where my application lives, this works pretty much as expected if the bootloader is present. There's meant to be some space for permanently stored values in the bootloader section, which I'll store using the Microchip/Atmel ASF4 flash read-erase-write routines.

From debugging point of view it'd be handy if I could do my stuff without the bootloader present, its design is not frozen yet among other things and the timeouts get a bit old after a few hundred reboots.

Trying to convince linker that the program entry point is in 0x0800 has been a resounding failure so far. Is it even possible to convince the ARM processor to skip the 1st 2kB and start executing at 0x0800 or it'll start at 0x0000, no matter what? Microchip has this application note that implies it should be possible to redefine the executable address but this doesn't work for me. I'm thinking the factory-installed bootloader in UC3 actually jumps to the 0x80002000, so that's why this is working.
https://microchip.my.site.com/s/article/How-to-retain-the-boot-loader-in-the-UC3-devices-while-application-code-is-programmed-through-debugger

Basically add this to linker script:

```
FLASH (rxai!w) : ORIGIN = 0x80002000, LENGTH = 0x0007E000 
PROVIDE (__executable_start = 0x80002000);. = 0x80002000;
```

I've also tried other variants of the same theme, all leading into processor croaking with a "memory out of bounds or read error". I've tried ENTRY and PROVIDES commented out things I've tried:

```
/* Memory Spaces Definitions */
MEMORY
{
  bootrom   (r) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x000007E8 
  userbytes (r)     : ORIGIN = 0x00000000 + LENGTH(bootrom), LENGTH = 0x00000018 
  rom       (rx)    : ORIGIN = 0x00000000 + LENGTH(bootrom) + LENGTH(userbytes), LENGTH = 0x00010000 - LENGTH(bootrom) - LENGTH(userbytes) */
  ram       (rwx)   : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x00002000 
}

/* The stack size used by the application. NOTE: you need to adjust according to your application. */
STACK_SIZE = DEFINED(STACK_SIZE) ? STACK_SIZE : DEFINED(__stack_size__) ? __stack_size__ : 0x800;

/*  ENTRY(Reset_Handler);*/
/*  PROVIDE(__executable_start = 0x00000800); */

/* Section Definitions */
SECTIONS
{
    .text 0x00000800:
    {
.
.
    } > rom
    .userbytes (NOLOAD) :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        KEEP(*(.calibrate))
    } > userbytes
```

I'm starting to think that the only way to make this work would be to make a minimal bootloader version that does nothing except jump to 0x0800 and/or Reset_Handler()?

Comment: sounds like you fully understand it, you dont need a minimal bootloader, a cortex-m put the address (ORRED with 1, 0x0801) in the second entry in the vector table, and the stack pointer value in the first word.  that is the minimal you would need to add to this at address 0x0000

Comment: old_timer's suggestion is good, as long as your main application sets the SCB_VTOR to the address of its vector itself.  If it expects the bootloader to do that then your minimal bootloader will have to do it.  Similarly any other setup that the application expects the bootloader to do will have to be in your "minimal" bootloader.  If your bootloader does loads of things that the application can't live without, then it may be easier just to take a copy of the existing bootloader and cut out the timeouts and whatever else you don't want.

Comment: @TomV The application runs happily without the bootloader as long as it starts at 0x0000, so it'll just redo the setup after the bootloader jumps to the start address. From what you guys are saying, I gather that there must be something written at 0x0000, no way around it. I guess just copying relevant lines of code from the bootloader to do the jump to 0x0800 and flashing that to the beginning of the flash would be the easiest way.

Comment: not all cores have a settable vtor.  Have to look at the cortex-m0.  if the application has their own vector table then booting into it is different cant branch to 0x8000.  so that needs to be known.  if it runs happily from 0x0000 then you do similar to what you answered mimic the reset with the stack pointer and reset address.

Comment: the application should set the vtor not the bootloader that calls it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this snippet cut from the bootloader code should do what I want. I'll see if I can do bare bones-version of that since since the main app will do the setup again, although it doesn't really matter if I'm doing redundant setup as long as it's <2kB.

Compile that and burn to start of memory space, then use the Microchip Studio debugger with linker set up to leave 1st 2kB alone to do my app development.

```
#define APP_START_ADDRESS (0x00000800)

void main(void)
{
    uint32_t msp            = *(uint32_t *)(APP_START_ADDRESS);
    uint32_t reset_vector   = *(uint32_t *)(APP_START_ADDRESS + 4);
     __set_MSP(msp);
    asm("bx %0"::"r" (reset_vector));
}
```

Comment: I would avoid using C real assembler is better for this. and would not use a function named main() in these types of applications.